# Legacy database - model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a legacy database in my rails app.

I would like to incorporate model validation in my application but it does not seem to work with legacy database.

** model Person **

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

set_table_name "EMI_PERSON"
set_primary_key "PER_ID"
attr_accessor :person_title
validates :PER_FORENAME, :presence => true

end
```

When I include `'validates :PER_FORENAME, :presence => true'` in my model, I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in PersonsController#edit

undefined method `validates' for Person(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Did you try `validates_presence_of`?

Comment: Can you rename tables/fields in the db? Everything would be so much easier :)

Comment: I wish I could but unfortunately, I am using a database which another java application uses :(

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Am going to try the 'validates_presence_of' method and will let you know if it works

Comment: validates_presence_of seems to work great...Thanks

Comment: This problem arises only with validation? Your model works well with the EMI_PERSON table?

Comment: @Kum: posted as an answer (so you can accept this as a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `validates_presence_of` instead of `validates`.